# Avoid duplicate code when api might return array or single object

Tags: node.js

I'm working with an API to consult car debits. If the car has more than one debit, the API returns an array of debits. If it has only one, it returns a single debit object (not an array with one element).
The problem is that I have to duplicate all the deserialization of this response checking whether the attribute is an array or a single object.

```js
const debits = []
if (car.debits.length > 0) {
    car.debits.forEach((debit: any) => {
        debits.push({
            id: uuidv1(),
            description: debit.description,
            label: debit.label,
            amount: parseInt(debit.amount, 10)
        })
    })

} else {
    debits.push({
        id: uuidv1(),
        description: debit.description,
        label: debit.label,
        amount: parseInt(debit.amount, 10)
    })
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this? I showed just a small example but the object is much larger and there are many other attributes that I have to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the API, you should probably have it return an array with a single element. If not, at the start of the function just force it into an array.

```
car.debits = car.debits.length ? car.debits : [car.debits]
```

If car.debits.length is undefined, which means it is not an array, you create an array and put the object inside it